# SSIS package not working for mutiple files

Tags: sql-server, ssis-2012

I have a SSIS package which is used to import multiple csv file in the Database. This SSIS package was working fine on SQL Server 2012 on windows 2012.Recently we have upgraded our DB hardware rebuild the database server to SQL server 2014. Now when we are running the same SSIS package on SQL server 2014 it is only processing one file at a time. I am not sure if any Integration Service setting we can check. I am sure permissions should be fine on the folder and the accounts

Comment: Could you please provide a scrrenshot of the package in question? How are you processing the files? Are you using "for each" or any other task? There is some setting dealing with parallelism, but I'm pretty sure it was available in 2012 as well...

Comment: my application executes the dtsx package which creates a single output file for multiple input file which is working fine for 2012 but not for 2014